# Python: convenient way to initialize lots of class members

Tags: python, variables, initialization, shortcut, self

If I have lots of class variables to initialize, any way to shorten the use of "self." ? That is, instead of doing:

```
self.variable1 = 1
self.variable2 = 10
self.variable3 = "hello"
etc.
```

is it possible to do some shortcut like:

```
with self: 
    variable1 = 1
    variable2 = 2
    variable3 = 'hello'
```

Just thought I could save on some typing if that's possible.  BTW - when putting in code fragments in here, is there a way to indent a whole block. I find that selecting a whole block and then hitting tab does not work.

Comment: Note to other readers. That use of `with` is from Visual Basic. the `with` statement in python has a completely different meaning.

Comment: This is also how the `with` keyword is used in Pascal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this, here's a way:

```
self.__dict__.update(
    variable1 = 1,
    variable2 = 2,
    variable3 = 'hello')
```

I'd usually just type `self` or use copy&paste in my editor.

Comment: Looks like the easiest way to go about doing it.  But it seems many are against the idea of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to do this, but I wouldn't suggest them. It hampers readability.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, just for fun:

```
myvars = { 'variable1': 1,
           'variable2': 10,
           'variable3': "Hello" }

for name, value in myvars.iteritems():
    setattr(self, name, value)
```